# Sort and print JSON output alphabetically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

I have a function that pulls a list of countries from a JSON array

```
function regionPlanOutput(networkGroupId) {
    document.getElementById("country_list").innerHTML = "";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET'
        , url: regionApiURL + '/api/v4/networkGroups/' + networkGroupId + '/countries?count=500'
        , dataType: 'json'
        , success: function (networkGroup) {
            jQuery.each(networkGroup.countryList, function (i, countryList) {
                var countryName = countryList.name;
                var flag = countryList.logoUrl;
                var countrycontent = '<li>' + countryName + '</li>';
                console.log(countrycontent)
                jQuery(countrycontent).appendTo("#country_list");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

At the moment it just prints the list in the order it pulls them from the array, How do I sort the output alphabetically based on the variable `countryName`?

Comment: can you include what the output JSON looks like?

Comment: Note that when you get to `success`, that `networkGroup` parameter is already a JavaScript object, not JSON. JSON is a string format, so talking about a JSON array is bad terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying the DOM inside the loop as you step through `networkGroup.countryList` (which makes sorting more complicated, and is a bad idea performance-wise anyway), capture the country names in a temporary array, sort that array, then drop it into the DOM in one go:

```
success: function (networkGroup) {
    var output = []; // temporary array
    jQuery.each(networkGroup.countryList, function (i, countryList) {
        output.push('<li>'+countryList.name+'</li>'); // capture each name in the temporary array.  We'll go ahead and include the <li> tags here since it won't affect the sort order
    });
    output.sort(); // sort it
    jQuery("#country_list").append(output.join('')); // drop it into the DOM
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

use the sort method on the returned array, should default to alphabetical since you're dealing with strings in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your `networkGroup.countryList` looks something like this:

```
countryList = [
    {name: "someName", logUrl: "http://example.com"},
    // ...etc.
]
```

You can sort by `countryList.name` like this:

```
countryList.sort(function(a, b){
    return (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0)
})
```

This will sort in place, so after you run that, your countryList will be changed to the sorted order. If you sort `networkGroup.countryList` before you call `jQuery.each` you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In your `success` function `networkGroup` is already a JavaScript `object` and not a `JSON` object.

So you just need to use [**Array.prototype.sort()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method with your `networkGroup.countryList` array to get the sorted array.

This is how should be your code:

```
success: function(networkGroup) {
  networkGroup.countryList = networkGroup.countryList.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.countryName.toUpperCase();
    var nameB = b.countryName.toUpperCase();
    if (nameA < nameB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  //The rest of your code 
}
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo snippet:

```js
var group = {
  countryList: [{
      countryName: "Vietnam",
      prop: "5224"
    },
    {
      countryName: "USA",
      prop: "000"
    },
    {
      countryName: "Palestine",
      prop: "5454"
    },
    {
      countryName: "Nigeria",
      prop: "1717"
    },
    {
      countryName: "Albania",
      prop: "54"
    },
    {
      countryName: "Belgium",
      prop: "1000"
    }
  ]
};



var sortArray = function sortArray(networkGroup) {
  networkGroup.countryList = networkGroup.countryList.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.countryName.toUpperCase();
    var nameB = b.countryName.toUpperCase();
    if (nameA < nameB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  return networkGroup.countryList;
}
console.log(sortArray(group));
```